# IOS - Problem on using FirebaseDynamicLinks

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I got the same problem on using FirebaseDynamicLinks
Also added -ObjC in build settings "Other Linker Flag"

Imported in AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FirebaseCore/FIRApp.h"
#import "FirebaseCore/FIROptions.h"
#import "FirebaseDynamicLinks/FIRDynamicLinks.h"
```

ERROR:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"OBJC_CLASS$_FIRComponent", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in FirebaseDynamicLinks(FIRDynamicLinks.o)
"OBJC_CLASS$_FIRDependency", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in FirebaseDynamicLinks(FIRDynamicLinks.o)
"OBJC_CLASS$_FIRComponentType", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in FirebaseDynamicLinks(FIRDynamicLinks.o)
"OBJC_CLASS$_FIRComponentContainer", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in FirebaseDynamicLinks(FIRDynamicLinks.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Try to reinstall pods again, clean and run the project.

Comment: i am not using cocopods.   added frameworks manually

Comment: Try to remove and add the framework, clean the build, run the project once.

Comment: i am still having the same problem  "Try to remove and add the framework, clean the build, run the project once"

Comment: @SivaMurugan Did you find the solution? If yes, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found that I didn't update my older Analytics framework and downloaded the new firebase SDK from google console and drag only the FirebaseDynamicLinks framework to my code.

So, I removed the old Analytics framework and drag the new Analytics frameworks to my code. Don't combine old and updated frameworks. Here is screenshot of Analytics and Dynamiclink framework.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those symbols are defined in FirebaseCore.framework.

Make sure that the FirebaseCore.framework that is being linked comes from the same distribution as the FirebaseDynamicLinks.framework.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the version of your firebaseCore framework and make sure the version is the same as the firebasedynamiclink framework.